# Compiling an AppleScript workflow dependent on script libraries into a self-contained app

Tags: applescript, automator

When building an AppleScript using Script Editor and some external `/Library/Script Libraries`, it is possible to make the final app self-contained by compiling it. I tested it by compiling a script that uses Dialog Toolkit Plus, and then removing that extension from the `Script Libraries` folder. The compiled app ran successfully, while the uncompiled version failed with -1728 (I guess it was).

Now my question is whether a similar technique is possible using Automator and a Run AppleScript step, where you would build a finished script into an app?

My goal is of course to distribute an app within a company and free the end user from the pre-installing hassle.

Comment: Automator apps have the same structure as an applescript app so it should be possible and you could likely test the viability in the same way.